# Adobe Creative SDK / Aviary produces blurry images when cropped

Tags: crop, aviary, adobecreativesdk

A frustrating issue I've come across when setting fixed dimensions for crop presets - the resulting image is blurry, even when using a high-res source.

The [documentation](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html) states:

> Fixed-pixel cropPresets perform a resize when applied.

But it seems very strange that it would produce such poor results.

**Example** ([original is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL9l9.jpg)):

Crop most of the image, using a preset of 120x155:

[image]

Resulting output:

[image]

Equivalent when resized with Preview:

[image]

It looks like the image is being cropped first and then being resized up, instead of it being resized down, and then cropped - which would produce better results.

Our app relies on high-resolution imaging and we are very keen to switch to Creative SDK but this is a massive issue for us. Any suggestions or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may have been fixed by the latest version of the web editor. Please try using this script tag to get version 3:

```
http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js
```

Comment: Thanks Ash, it's an improvement but the image quality is still lacking quite considerably. I'm putting together some examples comparing Photoshop, GD, Imagemagik resizes vs the results we're getting from Adobe Creative SDK. Hope that will help.

Comment: [Comparison between Creative Cloud, Photshop, Filestack, and PHP/GD](http://i.imgur.com/K3Y0EPj.png)

Comment: Thanks Ryan! In the comparison above, is "Creative Cloud" the Creative SDK Image Editor?

Comment: That's right Ash - we keep calling it that due to the branding on the UI.Hope it helps get to the bottom of the issue.